# PowerShell commands not recognized when called from VisualStudio 2017

Tags: powershell, visual-studio

I've written a function called `Deploy-App` which our developers use inside VisualStudio 2017 in `Build Events > Post-build event command line` to publish their application to a network share.

I've written another function, called `Invoke-Unlock` which unlocks folders + files that are locked on a remote server, directly from their machine.

Right now, they do `Invoke-Unlock` manually in PowerShell first, so that the Application is unlocked in the network share, then deploy the App in VisualStudio.

Now I've made `Invoke-Unlock` part of `Deploy-App` so the developers don't have to do this manually anymore. They can just call it with a switch like this `Deploy-App xy -InvokeUnlock`.

In `Invoke-Unlock` i use `Get-SmbShare` and `Get-SmbOpenFile`. Everything worked fine when using this function manually, but if they use it in VisualStudio, they get the following error message:

```
9>  Get-SmbShare : The term 'Get-SmbShare' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable 
9>  program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
9>  At \\server\install$\Powershell-Scripts\Functions\Invoke-Unlock.ps1:28 char:22
9>  +         $LocalPath = Get-SmbShare -CimSession $Session | ? { $_.Name  ...
9>  +                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~
9>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SmbShare:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
9>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
9>   
9>  Get-SmbOpenFile : The term 'Get-SmbOpenFile' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
9>  operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try 
9>  again.
9>  At \\server\install$\Powershell-Scripts\Functions\Invoke-Unlock.ps1:32 char:9
9>  +         Get-SmbOpenFile -CimSession $Session | ? { $_.Path -like "$En ...
9>  +         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
9>      + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SmbOpenFile:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
9>      + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
9>
```

The `Smb` commands are available since PowerShell 4.0. All Developers have PowerShell 5.1 on Windows 10.

So why are the commands not recognized? Does VisualStudio use another PowerShell Version somehow? Does anybody have an idea?

Edit:
i added `ipmo SmbShare` at the beginning of `Invoke-Unlock`, to make sure the module was loaded also in VisualStudio, but then I get this errormessage:

`ipmo : The specified module 'SmbShare' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.`

This makes me think that VisualStudio does not use default PowerShell Module directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual problem in such cases is that Visual Studio 2017 is 32-bit,
so will by default evoke the 32-bit version of PowerShell.
But when starting PowerShell manually on 64-bit Windows you are using
the 64-bit version of PowerShell.

This causes PowerShell to execute differently from inside than outside
Visual Studio.

The solution is to evoke specifically the 64-bit version from Visual Studio
using this syntax:

```
%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe
```

Comment: See [The 'Sysnative' folder in 64-bit Windows explained](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/sysnative-folder-64-bit-windows.htm) for accessing 64-bit tools from 32-bit code. This is a virtual folder that can be used for traversing to a file, but its "contents" cannot be listed.

Comment: well... I don't have a 32-bit software to test this, but in cmd.exe, windows startmenu, cmd for visualstudio `%WINDIR%\SysNative\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe "gci ; pause"` fails, while `%WINDIR%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\PowerShell.exe "gci ; pause"` works. but I will let the developers test this and come back to you

Comment: Developer just told me that the `SysNative` Path works. Thanks a lot Harry, that was very helpful